# HTML5/Javascript game dev - If I have more than one boundary, only the most recent one works

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

So basically what I have is a function called `createBoxBoundary`, which, when the player position is within certain limits, sets boundary variables to true. Pretty straightforward. However, when I call this function more than once in the main game loop, only the one most recently called works. Below is a sampling of my code

```
//It should be noted the player deminsions are 40x80
function createBoxBoundary(x,y,width,height){
    //right boundaries
    if(playerXPos + 40 == x && playerYPos + 80 >= y && playerYPos < y + height){
        boundaryRight = true;
    } else{boundaryRight = false;}

    //bottom boundaries
    if(playerYPos == y + height && playerXPos + 40 >= x && playerXPos <= x + width){
        boundaryTop = true;
    } else{boundaryTop = false;}

    //left boundaries
    if(playerXPos == x + width && playerYPos + 80 >= y && playerYPos <= y + height){
        boundaryLeft = true;
    } else{boundaryLeft = false;}

    //bottom boundaries
    if(playerYPos + 80 == y && playerXPos + 40 >= x && playerXPos < x + width){
        boundaryBottom = true;
    } else{boundaryBottom = false;}
}
```

I've also set up a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdCMG/6/)** with the full game code. And if anyone has advice on a better way to do collisions/boundaries in javascript, I'm open to that  as well. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not checking if `boundaryRight` is already set to true before checking what is value is for the second boundary.

Something like this should work:

```
boundaryRight = ( boundaryRight || ( playerXPos + 40 == x && playerYPos + 80 >= y && playerYPos < y + height );
```

I have also done some other tweaks in this jsFiddle that add some more flexibility of defining boundaries and other things. Also adds the ability to move in more than one direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/QdCMG/7/